# Percentage in background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, background-color, android-relativelayout

I'm kind of stuck with a problem and I hope you can help me. Im developing an Android application with Android Studio.

I have a TableLayout with 2 elements. The first column is a LinearLayout with a percentage painted in the background, and the second column, just a simple textview (for the example, I put two rows in it).

I have solved the problem with XML representation, and I need to do the same but programmatically. Here is my XML:

```
    <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/orionBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@color/orionRed">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/orionWhite"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/orionBackground"
            android:textColor="@color/orionWhite"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/orionBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@color/orionRed">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/orionWhite"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="There"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/orionBackground"
            android:textColor="@color/orionWhite"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I need to do the same but programmatically and I don't know how could be wrong with what Im doing. Here is my code:

```
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    /*TextView*/
    TextView textViewHelloWorld = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    textViewHelloWorld.setText("");
    textViewHelloWorld.setLayoutParams(
    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textViewHelloWorld.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    /*Child Layout*/
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    /*Here I set the percentage of the LinearLayout to 10*/
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10f);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params1);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A23934"));
    /*Textbox Added | I tested before the above line*/
    linearLayout.addView(textViewHelloWorld);
    /*Parent Layout*/
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,100f);
    LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    /*Finally, I added the LinearLayout into de parent LinearLayout*/
    parentLayout.addView(linearLayout,params);
    TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    TableRow.LayoutParams params10 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rowHeader.setLayoutParams(params10);
    /*Then, the linear layout is Added into de TableRow*/
    rowHeader.addView(parentLayout);
    /*And added to the row*/
    table.addView(rowHeader);
```

Visually, this is how I need to see it:

What I want to accomplish

[image]

This is for an app that will show the percentage of amount in a order book of cryptocurrencies.

My issue is that my solution print the whole background and should be print only a part of the background. The image above, prints the percentage, 30 and 60, defined by the layout_weight attribute, but when I do it programmatically doesnt work at all.

Why isnt working?

I really hope you can help me with this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try to set elevation to TextView like  `ViewCompat.setElevation(textViewHelloWorld, 10);`

so this be like

```
 TextView textViewHelloWorld = new TextView(getBaseContext());
textViewHelloWorld.setText("sample text");
textViewHelloWorld.setLayoutParams(
new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textViewHelloWorld.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
ViewCompat.setElevation(textViewHelloWorld, 10);
```

Comment: Hi Omi!.. Thanks for the answer. But the setElevation do nothing different. In what cases do I choose setElevation?.

Comment: `In what cases do I choose setElevation?` in some cases parent layout background cover the child layout so to avoid this you may add elevation greater than parent layout to elevate child layout...

Comment: Thanks Omi.. I will read about it. Maybe I need to change the way to achieve it